# Windows install on X99 board, USB compatibitlity issues?

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation

I've assembled a new PC for photo and video editing. 
PC component link: http://pcpartpicker.com/b/cs9WGX

Ram has been memtest for 48+ hours, no errors.
GPU was stress tested for 4 hours, no obvious errors or reboots.
CPU was stress tested for 4 hours, no errors.
Temps look great. SMART data show no obvious issues.

I had PCI-E slot issues with first mainboard, top slot population of the GPU resulted in no video output. I was able to use slot 3 to get video, and then managed to get Windows 7 SP1 Pro OEM installed onto the 950 Pro ( using Samsung NVMe drivers). Stability was terrible, and windows error logging showed PCI-E issues. I pulled the 950 and installed to the 2TB SSD. Same stability issues. **RMA'd board.**

New board has had no problem initializing video output from top slot, but came with older bios 1.4. I (stupidly??) updated the bios to 3.2 and have not been able to complete a windows installation.

I've tried Win7 SP1 disk, Win7SP1 USB with Intel Creator Installer added USB 3 drivers, Win 8(disk and usb), Win 8.1(disk and usb), and 10(usb).

This board does have dual bios, but looks like I updated both chips :|, and I've yet to figure out a way to downgrade the bios back to 1.4 or 1.7 to see if that helps... **a recent review on Newegg of another customer with same board said he had major stability issues with bios versions beyond 1.x with the Xeon v3 family.**

I believe my issue in installing Windows to this board lies in the USB hand-off and compatibility issues. I don't recall the CSM and USB settings I used on the first board. So, I created a spreadsheet with all possible USB setting combinations and went through it systematically and recorded the result. **Most times the installer would hang at the language screen, reboot at the language screen, or simply have no USB support once at the language screen.**

The only minute success I've had was the Win7 SP1 OEM USB (with USB 3.0 drivers added via Intel Installer Creator) plugged into a USB2 port, with two scenarios:

USB settings as
Intel USB 3.0 mode: Enabled
Legacy USB Support: Auto
Legacy USB Support: Enabled
USB Compatibility Patch: Enabled
**Result: Am able to get through installation setup, but hangs after "Copying files"**

USB settings as
Intel USB 3.0 mode: Enabled
Legacy USB Support: Enabled
Legacy USB Support: Enabled
USB Compatibility Patch: Disabled
**Result: Boots sporadically, Am able to get through installation setup, but hangs after "Copying files"**

On new board, I've only tried installing to the 950 Pro. I've not tried using the above USB settings and attempting to install to 2TB SSD.

Comment: I assume since you are booting from a USB 3.0 device you have added the USB 3 drivers to the Windows 7 .ISO?

Comment: I used the Intel Installer Creator to add USB 3.0 drivers to the Win7 USB image.

Comment: I suggest you make some edits to your question.  You have a good amount of information and it is hard to follow honestly.  You don't even mention that fact.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've added that above and formatted a bit.

Comment: Ramhound, you seem to be a large contributor here. While I appreciate your willingness to respond promptly to this new question, your comment about editing the question left out details as to what you might have recommended editing. The level of effort and debugging I've put into this board over 3 months time is far beyond what I can pare down into a 5 sentence question.  AGAIN -- Thank you for your willingness to help.

Comment: Also, a USB 3.0 drive will not need USB 3 Drivers as long as its used in a USB 2 port.

Comment: You replied to my comment with important information. Do you need me to tell you that information should be in your question?  I don't like your condescending comment

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Sorry for offending you. Again, I appreciate that you responded to the question at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**The BIOS versions of this motherboard above 1.8 DO NOT WORK for Xeon V3 family.** ASRock does not acknowledge this and support will be of no help.

Downgraded BIOS version to 1.8 and have had no issue with my second board.

**Otherwise the USB handoff will not occur correctly.**